# Logic of Ugly Numbers in C

Tags: c, logic

Following from [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ugly-numbers/), I am trying to develop my own logic to generate a sequence of ugly numbers. But every time all the numbers are printed.

I am determining if the first 3 prime factors of the number are 2, 3 and 5 and placing them in a count variable determining the total count of prime factors of a number x.

If the count is greater than 3, the number is not ugly.

Here is the code:

```
/* To generate a sequence of Ugly numbers 
   Ugly numbers are numbers whose only prime factors are 2, 3 or 5. The sequence
   1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, …
   shows the first 11 ugly numbers. By convention, 1 is included.
*/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int isprime(int x)
{
    int i;
    for(i=2;i<=sqrt(x);i++)
        if(x%i==0)
            return 0;
    return 1;
}

int isUgly(int x)
{
    int count=0; //To maintain the count of the prime factors. If count > 3, then the number is not ugly
    int i;
    for(i=2;i<=sqrt(x);i++)
    {
        if(isprime(i) && x%i==0)
        {
            count++;
            if(count > 3)
                return 0; // Not ugly
        }   
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i,n=10;
    printf("\n The ugly numbers upto %d are : 1 ",n);
    for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
    {
        if(isUgly(i))
            printf(" %d ",i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Step though the code with a debugger.

Comment: A Google search for 'ugly numbers' comes up with the [definition](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ugly-numbers/): _Ugly numbers are numbers whose only prime factors are 2, 3 or 5. By convention, 1 is included._'  So, by this definition, a number is ugly if you can repeatedly divide it (exactly) by 2, then 3, then 5, and the sequence of values ends at 1.  If it ends at some other number, then it isn't ugly and the last value in the sequence is a product of one or more primes other than 2, 3 or 5.  (The Google search also uncovers a number of SO questions on the subject.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version of `isUgly()` that seems to work for me.

```
int isUgly(int x)
{
    int i;
    static int factors[] = {2, 3, 5};

    // Boundary case...
    // If the input is 2, 3, or 5, it is an ugly number.
    for ( i = 0; i < 3; ++i )
    {
       if ( factors[i] == x )
       {
          return 1;
       }
    }

    if ( isprime(x) )
    {
       // The input is not 2, 3, or 5 but it is a prime number.
       // It is not an ugly number.
       return 0;
    }

    // The input is not a prime number.
    // If it is divided by 2, 3, or 5, call the function recursively.
    for ( i = 0; i < 3; ++i )
    {
       if ( x%factors[i] == 0 )
       {
          return isUgly(x/factors[i]);
       }
    }

    // If the input not a prime number and it is not divided by
    // 2, 3, or 5, then it is not an ugly number.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the code a little bit and what happens if a number has factors beyond 2, 3 or 5?

Comment: It falls off the last `for` loop and returns `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
#include<stdio.h>

long int n, count=1;

void check(long int i)
{
    if(i==1){
        ++count;
        return;
    }
    else if(i%2==0)
        check(i/2);

    else if(i%3==0)
        check(i/3);

    else if(i%5==0)
        check(i/5);
    else
        return;
}

void main(){

    for(n=1;;n++){

        check(n);

        if(count==1000){
            printf("%ldth no is %ld\n",count,n);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```